# Locale set with a custom listener gets overridden

Tags: symfony, localization

My intention is to set the locale based on the Accept-Language HTTP request header.

I've created the custom LocaleListener class and configured it at config/services.yaml with a priority higher than LocaleListener, as instructed here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html

The logic contained in the `onKernelRequest()` method succeeds at retrieving the locale, which I pass to the `setLocale()` method.

Echoing the current locale in this same file returns the expected locale (the one defined by the user's browser). However, down the line, this locale is overridden, changed to the application default.

That's where the problem is. I need to identify what is overriding the locale and what are the possible solutions. The Symfony documentation did not go in such depth. I intend to contribute to the docs with what I find.

This is a Symfony 4 application running on GNU/Linux.

I've collected the output of `php bin/console debug:event kernel.request`:

```
Registered Listeners for "kernel.request" Event
===============================================

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                                          Priority  
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #1      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure()                     2048      
  #2      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest()             256       
  #3      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest()                     128       
  #4      App\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest()                                               110       
  #5      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::setDefaultLocale()                     100       
  #6      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest()                      32        
  #7      Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest()   24        
  #8      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest()                      16        
  #9      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleAwareListener::onKernelRequest()                 15        
  #10     Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::configureLogoutUrlGenerator()      8         
  #11     Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelRequest()                  8         
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

As you can see, there is my custom listener, above all other locale-related listeners.

I've tried to set its priority so it is executed AFTER setDefaultLocale(), but in the end the locale was still the default, 'en'.

And this is the custom listener code, from src/EventListener/:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class LocaleListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // LOGIC TO RETRIEVE LOCALE

        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }
}
```

Observation 01: The $locale variable, when echoed, returns the expected string.

Observation 02: Echoing $request->getLocale() inside the above method returns the expected string, which means the locale is successfully changed at this point.

And the following is the listener configuration at the bottom of config/services.yaml

```
    App\EventListener\LocaleListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 110 }
```

The locale is expected to be changed according to the languages defined on the browser - first one is 'pt' Portuguese; however the locale continues to be set to default, 'en'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the router.

The router is configured to use **prefixes**, which  determine the locale, on all routes, such as /pt or /en. I just had to disable them, so the application would successfully determine the locale based on my browser locales.

Now I just need to figure out how to keep locale prefixes available to use, while still primarily using the Accept-Language information. The prefixes would then act as overrides to this automatically defined locale. This is how a lot of popular websites work, even though it's not a best practice to serve different contents through a single URL.